# Appearance change after refresh

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, web-applications, page-refresh

The css and the appearance  is OK on the first time I open the page (after cleaning the cache). After refresh, a part of page change, (the padding  direction of a div). Another refresh does the same. 
The css itself doesn't change but the appearance of the div does.

If I refresh the page when the developer tools is open, the appearance doesn't change and the page is like it suppose to be.

Any idea why does it happen? 
Thank you!

Comment: There are way to many things it could be...

we would need to see some code/ a website to help :)

Comment: can you please post a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

Try here: http://ask.metafilter.com/200230/My-webpage-wont-update-unless-I-hit-the-refresh-button

Maybe your page is not loading/catching your last update and is catching a previous version until you refresh.
The bad behavior may be caused because on your latest version you missed something somewhere in your code, but you had it right previously.

Try opening it into another browser and see what happens, I guess it will not change if you refresh the page. If it doesn't, this should be a browser problem, not coding. Then try to get something like this on your code:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;  /* Safari-Chrome */
-moz-border-radius: 10px;     /* Firefox */
-ms-border-radius: 10px;      /* IE i think */
-o-border-radius: 10px;       /* Opera */
border-radius: 10px;          /* default */
```